# Export/Import Queue configuration - Solace

Tags: solace, solace-mq

How to export/import Queue configuration from One VPN to another VPN in Solace Appliance.

Answer (score 3):

There is no straightforward way to export a specific queue configuration. You'll need to export the entire Message VPN configuration and sieve out the queue configuration.

Specifically, through CLI on a **primary** appliance:

1. Export the config to a file (note the redirection operator `>`):

   ```
   solace> show current-config message-vpn <vpn_name> > <export_file>
   ```
2. Open the exported text file and extract the queue configuration portion.

   a. It is found in the section:

   ```
   ! Create Message Spool: "vpn_name"
   message-spool message-vpn "vpn_name"
   ```

   b. Queues are created in:

   ```
     create queue "queue_name"
       ...
       exit
   ```

   c. In addition, if using JNDI, look out for the JNDI section and grab the corresponding queue:

   ```
     ! Create JNDI: "vpn_name"
     jndi message-vpn "vpn_name"
       ...
       create queue "jndi_queue_name"
         property "physical-name" "queue_name"
       exit
       ...
   ```

   d. The extracted configuration should look something like:

   ```
   message-spool message-vpn "vpn_name"
     create queue ...
     ...
   exit

   jndi message-vpn "vpn_name"
     create queue ...
       ...
   exit
   ```
3. Import the extracted configuration in CLI:

   ```
   solace> enable
   solace# configure
   solace(configure)# source script <extracted_config> stop-on-error
   ```